# How to find the maximum distance from a "centerline" to the edge of a surrounding irregular polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, distance

Outside of QGIS I generated an irregular polygon from a line so it always contains it. If I did a buffer over the original line what distance do I need for that buffer polygon to cover all the orange polygon.

Is there an algorithm or process to find the maximum distance between the black line and the edge (at any side) of the orange polygon.

[image]

For this section, at a glance it should be around that green line in the image below, but the shapes are 73km long and probably there are larger distances.

Perhaps the line should be measured perpendicular to the tangent, because it could find lots of larger distances in other directions.
Any hints on how to achieve this?

Comment: You don't say which GIS software you are using?

Comment: Also have you tried search this forum? Search for words like "perpendicular centreline", "maximum perpendicular width".

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but possibly you are looking for the Hausdorff distance. That is implemented in JTS and GEOS (but read the API documentation on limitations. It will be exposed in some applications that use those (e.g. PostGIS or Spatialite).

Comment: Does the line have to be perpendicular to the centerline?  Do you need to know the value for both sides of the line?

Comment: I think you'll find that the green line is NOT the longest line perpindicular to the tangent of the black line -- that occurs on the promontory two "bays" further west, from a quarter of the way to the western end of the black line.

Comment: Can you formulate the original problem? The question you asked is not entirely clear.